# Multer MemoryStorage buffer sometimes does not work

Tags: node.js, multer

As a simple test I tried uploading a file with memory storage and saving the buffer in a variable. Then with another route retrieving the file.
Like this:

```
var multer  = require('multer');
var storage = multer.memoryStorage();
var upload = multer({
  storage: storage
});
var fileBuffer = null;
var fileName = null;
var fileBase64 = null;
router.post('/attachment', upload.any(), function (req, res, next) {
  fileBuffer = req.files[0].buffer;
  fileName = req.files[0].originalname;
  fileBase64 = fileBuffer.toString('base64');
  return res.send({ok: true});
});
router.get('/file', function (req, res, next) {
  res.type(fileName); //for setting mime type
  //return res.end(fileBase64, 'base64');
  return res.end(fileBuffer);
});
```

The problem is that it consistently works for some files and does not work for others.

It works for some png files and not for others, it does not work for pdf (number of pages are consistent, but all pages are empty), it worked for some .doc and zip files.

The problem occurs if I use the buffer directly (as in the code showed) or if I use the fileBase64 variable (commented in the GET /file route). Again, it is consistent: it works for the same files and does not work for the same files.

As a simple form for testing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="/attachment" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I guess I have to do something else to have this working for any kind of file. Maybe using the buffer is not the way.

Any kind of help is really welcomed. Thanks in advance.

I am using:
node.js 0.10.33
express 4.12.2
multer 1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is no problem with multer.
It is demonstrated by saving the buffer to the file system. The file gets saved correctly in all cases.

```
fs.writeFile("/my-uploads/" + fileName, fileBuffer, function(err) {
    if(err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("The file was saved!");
  });
```

The problem occurs when returning the buffer in the code:

```
router.get('/file', function (req, res, next) {
  res.type(fileName); //for setting mime type
  //return res.end(fileBase64, 'base64');
  return res.end(fileBuffer);
});
```

So this is another question to solve.